# How to test for equivalence in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, scheme, equality

[Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) knows three different equivalence operators: `eq?`, `eqv?`, `equal?`. Sere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16299246/402322) for details. In short: `eq?` tests references, `eqv?` tests values and `equal?` recursively tests the values of lists. I would like to write a Java generic which needs the functionality of Scheme´s `equal?`.

I tried to use Java´s [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, because I thought it does a value comparison, because for a reference comparison the `==` operator exists and there is no need for `equals` to do the same. But this assumption is completely wrong, because `equals` in Java is completely unreliable. Sometimes it does a value comparison and sometimes it does a reference comparison. And one can not be sure which class does a reference comparison and which class does a value comparison.

This means that `equals` can not be used in a generic, because the generic would not do the same for all types. And it is also not possible to restrict the generic type in a way that only types are acceptable which implement the correct value comparison.

So the question is: how to do a reliable value comparison in a generic? Do I have to write it on my own from scratch?

By the way: I think Java´s equal failure does not start with [Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777266/402322). It starts already with Object. I think it is wrong that `equals` for two objects returns `false`. It must return `true`, because if you do a value comparison of something which does not have a value the values can not differ and therefor they must be the same. Scheme does it in that way and it is perfectly reasonable: `(equal? (vector) (vector)) -> #t`.

Comment: You can use `SomeClass.getDeclaredMethod("equals", Object.class)` to check if a class overrides the `Object.equals(Object)` method. If a class does override it, chances are that it does some form of a value comparison. However there is still absolutely no guarantee that it does exactly the kind of comparison you are looking for.

Comment: You can also use the same type of methods (`SomeClass.getDeclaredFields()` then `myField.setAccessible(true)` and `myField.get(myObject)` you'd also have to use `SomeClass.getSuperclass()` and do the same comparisons on all of the superclasses' fields) to look up the fields of two objects and recursively check if they hold the same values however that sounds like overkill.

Comment: Welcome to OOP, basically.

Comment: @PaulBellora Java, welcome to Java. We have structural equivalence else where

Comment: @jozefg Interesting - what are some examples?

Comment: @PaulBellora OCaml, Go, Dylan, CLOS is structural equivalence by default I believe. The main problem here though is that **every** class is by default equatable which is just wrong. Most things since Java haven't made this mistake.

Comment: @jozefg That's a good point. Just to clarify, you're saying there should have been an `Equatable` interface, etc? Or are you talking about the lack of a self-type that would allow `equals(ThisType)` instead of `equals(Object)`?

Comment: @PaulBellora Equatable interface. Some things really shouldn't be structurally compared.

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme, list equivalence is based completely on the structure of the items.

In Java by comparison, equality is context-dependent depending on the type of object, and may use some or all of the internal structure in its equivalence calculation.  What it means for two objects of the same type to be "equal" is up to the object type to determine, so long as the [general contract for equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is met (most notably that it forms an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) with all other objects).

Assuming all types used in a program have a reasonable `equals` definition, they *should* have a "reliable" value comparison, at least in the sense of the object oriented paradigm.

Returning to the analogous Java `equal?` implementation.  It's a bit hard to piece together from the question's phrasing, but from context clues it appears that this is also attempting to operate on lists of items.  The [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method on Java's [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) type already implements behavior directly analogous to Scheme's `equals?` operation:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*. (Two elements e1 and e2 are *equal* if `Objects.equals(e1, e2)`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

This definition also means that recursive list structures also work in a similar manner as Scheme's `equals?` operation.

Note that the `List` behavior is notably different from that of Java's array type (which you mention in your question).  Arrays in Java are a fairly low-level type, and do not support much of the typical object-oriented functionality one might expect.  Of particular note, for equality, arrays are compared by object reference rather than by a structural comparison of the items in the array.  There are ways to do sensible equality comparison on arrays using methods in the `Arrays` class (e.g. [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) and [`Arrays.deepEquals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object%5B%5D))).

---

As an aside, to address your postscript about the equality of two bare `Object`s.

```java
assert !(new Object().equals(new Object()))
```

From an object-oriented perspective, it is sensible that two bare objects be equal only if they're the same reference.  First, as mentioned above, there is not a direct relation between an object's internal structure and its equality, so there's no *need* for them to be equal.  There is virtually no context as to what two different instances of `Object` represent from a object modeling perspective, so there's no inherent conceptual way to tell that these two objects are logically the "same" thing.

---

In summary, assuming all the types in your list have a *sensible* version of `equals()` defined per their object's type, Java's `List.equals()` behaves directly analogously to Scheme's `equals?` operation.