# Differences between equal strings

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a simple parser in `Racket`, using the `parser-tools`. I got a behaviour which I could not explain (I am a Racket newbie, perhaps that is trivial).

Consider the following code:

```
#lang racket
(require parser-tools/yacc
         parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre))


(define-tokens value-tokens   ;;token which have a value
  (STRING-VALUE ))
(define-empty-tokens op-tokens ;;token without a values
  (EOF))
(define-lex-abbrevs ;;abbreviation 
  [STRING (:+ (:or (:/ "a" "z") (:/ "A" "Z") (:/ "0" "9") "." "_" "-"))]
  )


(define lex-token
  (lexer
   [(eof) 'EOF]
   ;; recursively call the lexer on the remaining input after a tab or space.  Returning the "1+1")
   ;; result of that operation.  This effectively skips all whitespace.
   [(:or #\tab #\space #\newline)
    (lex-token input-port)]
   [(:seq STRING) (token-STRING-VALUE lexeme)]
   ))

(define test-parser
  (parser
   (start query)
   (end EOF)
   (tokens value-tokens op-tokens)
   (error (λ(ok? name value) (printf "Couldn't parse: ~a\n" name)))

   (grammar
    (query [(STRING-VALUE)      $1])
    )))

(define s (open-input-string 
           "abcd123"))

(define res
  (test-parser (lambda () (lex-token s))))

(define str "abcd123")
```

After those definitions, `res` is a string:

```
> (string? res)
#t
```

and so is `str`.

If I try to execute a comparison with the `"abcd123"` string I get two different results:

```
> (eq? res "abcd123")
#f

> (eq? str "abcd123")
#t
```

Why is that? What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal?, and = in scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare strings with `equal?`.

Answer (score 2):

Like many programming languages there is a difference between same object and two objects that look the same. You probably should have a look at the Question about [the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal? and =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme)

Racket has [string=?](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string=?#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string~3d~3f%29%29) which compares strings specifically and might be faster than the less specific `equal?`.