# Scheme equality of returning value

Tags: function, boolean, return, scheme

I'm at beginning with `Scheme`. I'm trying to check equality of returning boolean value

```
(cond [(= (Test number) #t) 1])]
```

If my test function returns true, my main function should return 1. But I get `contract violation error`. Is there anybody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is only used to compare numbers. `eq?` would be the correct equality procedure if you really need to check if something really is `#t`.

Normally any value not #f is considered a true value and if that is ok you should do this:

```
(cond [(Test number) 1]
      [else 'else-case])
```

Your `cond` misses a default case, like the one I've added. In case your `Test` return #f you really need it or else the result is undefined.

A related question on SO is [What is the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal?, and = in scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme)