# Why are these string different in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am running following code:

```
(define  myframe  (new frame% [label "myframe"]))

(define tf1 (new text-field%  [parent myframe] [label "tf1"]))
(define tf2 (new text-field%  [parent myframe][label "tf2"]))
(define tf3 (new text-field%  [parent myframe][label "tf3"]))

(send  myframe show #t)

(define combined_str (string-append (send tf1 get-value) "-" (send tf2 get-value) "-" (send tf3 get-value) )) 
(println combined_str)
(if (eq? "--" combined_str) "same" "different")
```

Output is:

```
"--"
"different"
```

The combined_str is "--" because the text-fields are blank. But it is not coming as same as "--".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal?, and = in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme) (Since these operators in Racket are compatible with Scheme standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by using `eq?` instead of `equal?`. See [Object Identity and Comarpison](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=eq%3F#%28part._model-eq%29) for more, and also [What is the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal?, and = in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme). In short, `eq?` does a pointer comparison, which isn't what you want.

Examples:

```
> (eq? "--" (string-append "-" "-"))
#f
> (equal? "--" (string-append "-" "-"))
#t
> (string=? "--" (string-append "-" "-"))
#t
```