# Error message- `expects a number as 1st argument, given string

Tags: struct, racket, operator-keyword

Error message- `expects a number as 1st argument, given 'hearts`

I have to make a code without using equal? in solution
my code looks like this

```
(define-struct card (suit value))

(define (card=? str-1 str-2)
  (cond
    [(and (= (card-suit str-1) (card-suit str-2))
          (= (card-value str-1) (card-value str-2))) true]
    [else false]))


(check-expect (card=? (make-card 'hearts 3) (make-card 'hearts 3)) true)
```

Edit - the question goes like this for further info

In the card game “crazy eights” players take turns playing a card in the center, with the goal
of being the first player without any cards in their hand. Players must play a card that matches
the suit of the center card, with two exceptions. First, a player may instead play a card that
matches the value of the center card. Second, eights are “wild”, so a player may always play
an eight. When a player plays an eight, they say the name of a suit. The eight is treated as
having this suit, even if it does not. For example, if a player plays the eight of spades, and
says “hearts”, then the next card played must be a “hearts” card (or another eight).
Instead of playing a card, the player may draw a card. If they can play the new card they may
do so, otherwise this is the end of their turn.
When a player runs out of cards, they have won the hand. The winning player receives points
based on what cards the other players are holding.

For this question we will represent cards using the Card type:

```
(define-struct card (suit value))
;; A Card is a (make-card Sym Nat)
;; requires: suit is one of ’hearts, ’diamonds, ’clubs, or ’spades
;; value between 1 and 13, using 11 for Jack, 12 for Queen, and 13 for King.
```

Note: We are representing these cards with a computer, so it is easy enough to actually change
the eight of spades into an eight of hearts when it is played! For that reason, in the following
functions you may assume that the current suit is equal to the suit of the current card in the
center, even if the center card is an eight.

A)

Write a function `card=?` which consumes two Card structures and produces true if
they represent the same playing card, and false otherwise. You must not use `equal?`
in your solution. For example, `(card=? (make-card ’hearts 3) (make-card ’hearts 3))`
produces true

b)

Write a function `crazy-count` which consumes a list of Card structures and the current
center Card, and produces the number of Card structures in the list that can legally be
played in the center.

Answer (score 2):

You forget the whole error message which tells you which procedure complains:

```
=: expects a number as 1st argument, given 'hearts
```

`=` compares numbers. eg. `(= 3 5) ; ==> #f`. You are probably looking for `eq?` since it compares if it's the same object and symbols that look the same are in fact the same object. For a more general check to see if two things looks the same you should use `equal?` eg `(equal? "hello" "hello") ;==> #t`.

Comment: but `"hello"` is a string over here I have symbol `'heart` so it doesn't work

Comment: `equal?` works on everything that looks the same, including symbols, but `eq?` is the obvious choice. Se http://stackoverflow.com/q/16299246/1565698