# Searching a defined list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I have this list

```
 (define masterList(list redApple chickenLeg porkLoin milkD baguetteBread orangeJuice beanCan))
```

I am trying to make a function called lookup that will take an integer and return the element from the list that matches that integer. The list contains elements from a structure in this format

```
(define-struct storeItem (id des cost))
```

So I will be passing an integer that represents id and I want storeItem to be retuned.

For instance -

```
(define redApple (make-storeItem 0 "red delicious apple" 1.99))
```

If I searched masterList and passed it 0, I would expect redApple to be returned.

Any help on the syntax?

```
(define (contains masterList x)
(cond 
    ((null? masterList) #f)
    ((eq? (car masterList) x) #t)
    (else (contains (cdr masterList) x))))
```

This is what I am trying to make work.

It returns true/false correctly based on what I pass it.

(contains materList redApple) returns true.

How can I modify this to return redApple if 0 is entered?

```
;; These are the constructors to make the elements in our structure
   (define redApple (make-storeItem 0 "red delicious apple" 1.99))
   (define chickenLeg (make-storeItem 1 "boned chicken" 2.99))
   (define porkLoin (make-storeItem 2 "processed pork" 4.99))
   (define milkD (make-storeItem 3 "vitamin d milk" 3.99))
   (define baguetteBread (make-storeItem 4 "french bread" 0.99))
   (define orangeJuice (make-storeItem 5 "fruit juice drink)" 1.49))
   (define beanCan (make-storeItem 6 "beans in a can" 2.49)


;; Creating a list that we will use as our master list which contains elements from our structure
(define masterList(list redApple chickenLeg porkLoin milkD baguetteBread orangeJuice beanCan))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your general structure is correct, but you're not testing the correct condition with

```
(eq? (car masterList) x)
```

You don't want to compare `x` with the whole element of the list, just with its `id` component. So that should be:

```
(= (storeItem-id (car masterList)) x)
```

Also, to compare numbers you should use `=` or `eqv?` rather than `eq?`. See [What is the difference between eq?, eqv?, equal?, and = in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299246/what-is-the-difference-between-eq-eqv-equal-and-in-scheme?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If you want to get the object with the ID, rather than just `#true` or `#false`, return `(car masterList)` when the ID matches.

```
(define (find-storeItem masterList x)
  (cond ((null masterList) #false)
        ((= (storeItem-id (car masterList)) x) (car masterList))
        (else (find-storeItem (cdr masterList) x))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, it actually helped a lot.

Whenever I run with your suggested code I get 

car: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:

Comment: I had a missing parenthesis, I guess you fixed that the wrong way.

Comment: Which parenthesis are missing?

Comment: The second `)` in `(storeItem-id (car masterList))`

Comment: Thank you I do see where it was wrong. My code runs now but it seems my list is just 7 elements called #<storeItem>, any idea? I will edit my original code to show my constructors and list.

Comment: The question says it's a list of structures, not a list of item numbers.

Comment: Basically it is a list of structure objects. So I want to perform functions like getid, gettotalcost, ect by navigating the list to find these desired attributes. In the function I am currentyl working on, it would be entering the id number and getting the item it goes to. So 0 would return redApple.

Comment: Your function just returns `#true` or `#false` depending on whether the ID is found. If you want to actually return the object, return `(car masterList)` instead of `#true`.

Comment: That is correct, I was using #t and #f to see if it was working correctly, I apologize I did not make that clear originally. I want to input a number and return the corresponding grocery item that has the input as its id number. However at this point I think I may have created my list incorrectly since all the items in the list are #<storeItem> instead of redApple, chickenLeg...ect.