# Compare two variables if I don't know their type

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm learning Scheme and I want to compare two variables, but I don't know which type will have each of them.

On this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719745/68571), tells when to use =, eqv?, equal? and eq?, but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

My problem is that, the variables could be:

1. List: `'(1 2)` or `'((10) 2)`.
2. String: `'sunny`.
3. Number: `2`.

So I could be comparing a number with a list, or a list with a string.

I have this code:

```
(define contains?
  (lambda (lst element)
    (cond
      [(null? lst) #f]
      [(equal? (car lst) element) #t]
      (else [(contains? (cdr lst) elements)]))))
```

Which operator could I use to compare two of these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test them for *equality*, then [`equal?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._equal%7E3f%29%29) is your best bet, it's the most general equality predicate and as such it works on multiple data types, and does recursive comparisons for the cases of lists, vectors, etc.:

> Two values are equal? if and only if they are eqv?, unless otherwise specified for a particular datatype.
>
> Datatypes with further specification of equal? include strings, byte strings, pairs, mutable pairs, vectors, boxes, hash tables, and inspectable structures. In the last six cases, equality is recursively defined; if both v1 and v2 contain reference cycles, they are equal when the infinite unfoldings of the values would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Oscars answer. There are type specific procedures like `string=?`, `char=?`, and `=` for numbers, but to compare on general there are 3:

- `eq?` tests if two arguments are the same value, as in created at the same instant or pointer equal.
- `eqv?` tests if two primitive/scalar/atomic values look the same when displayed
- `equal?` tests if two values look the same

Also, what is `#t` for `eq?` is guaranteed to be `#t` for `eqv?` abd what is `#t` for `eqv?` is guaranteed to be `#t` for `equal?`.

I have read books that completely skip `eqv?` and just keep `eq?` and `equal?` as general comparison. A fair amount of procedures that compare stuff have 3 versions of the 3 methods of comparison across the board. Eg. `member` (`equal?`), `memv` (`eqv?`), `memq` (`eq?`).

About `eq?`: We are guaranteed that `'()`, `#t`, `#f` and the symbols, like `'test` would evaluate to the same value each and every time so they are always pointer equal. Other values might be, like number between a billion, but you have no guarantee all implementations will do it. `(eq? 10 10) ; ==> #f` is correct according to the standard as well as `(eq? '(a) '(a)) ; ==> #t`. In fact the two examnples can have any result and it's OK for the report. Notice how I say you are guaranteed to be `#t` withe `eqv?` if `eq?` yuilds `#t` but not vice versa. If something is `eqv?` you still have no idea what `eq?` would be.